# Simple jQuery slider script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have a simple jQuery slider but cant get multiple instances of it to work on the page, I am sure its an easy fix but my brain is just not co-operating atm

```
function testSlide() {
    var testAnim = document.querySelector(".testWrap");
    jQuery(".testWrap.animated ul img.dotNav").appendTo(jQuery('.testNav'));
    jQuery(".testWrap.animated ul > li:gt(0)").hide();
    jQuery(".testNav.animated > img.dotNav:gt(0)").addClass('inactivedot').removeClass('reddot');

    setInterval(function () {
        jQuery('.testWrap.animated ul > li:first')
            .stop(100)
            .fadeOut(100)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(100)
            .end();

        jQuery('.testWrap.animated ul > li:first').appendTo('.testWrap ul');
        jQuery('.testNav.animated> img:last-child')
            .prependTo('.testNav');


    }, 5000);
    jQuery(".testWrap").hover(function () {
        testAnim.classList.remove('animated');
    },

    function () {
        testAnim.classList.add('animated'); //Start the animation when mouse out
    });
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you add HTML? or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0):

if im right you can convert your code to a jquery plugin for create a multiple instance of your slider in your page 
here's the link as i googled:

https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/